# assembly nasm input float values into array

Tags: assembly, nasm

working on inputing floating point values into an array, then adding them up and getting a sum

so far i have this code for it, but my flag that checks to see if an input is 0 to exit the loop for entering floats, keeps on going(endless loop)

so far I can read an input and output it immediately, but dont know how to store into array

```
    %include "asm_io.asm"

segment .bss
array1      resd    20
segment .data
done        db  "That was ridiculously incredible! Bye!", 0
segment .text
    extern puts, _printf, scanf, dump_line, stack_dump, geomean
    global asm_main

asm_main:
    enter 0,0
    pusha
;Declare Array:
    push 5
    push 0
    push array1

    call    read_sarray32

    ;call getfloat
    ;call putfloat

    xor ebx, ebx
    mov eax, 1
    int 80h

    mov eax, done
    call    print_string

    popa
    leave
    ret

;beginning of get float
;*******************************getFLoat:*****************************
segment .bss
;
segment .data
    fmt1        db "%lf", 0
    enterNumber     db "Enter Your Float Number: ", 0
segment .text
getfloat:
    push ebp
    mov eax, enterNumber
    call    print_string
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 8
    lea eax, [ebp-8]
    push eax
    push fmt1
    call scanf
    add esp, 8

    fld qword [ebp -8]
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
;Beginning of putfloat
;************************putfloat:*****************************************
segment .bss
;
segment .data
    fmt2 db 10, "The number is: %f", 10, 10
segment .text
putfloat:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 8

    fst qword [ebp - 8]
    push fmt2
    call printf
    add esp, 12

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
;*********************READ array*************************************************
segment .bss
;
segment .data
prompt2     db  "Do you have more inputs? (-1 = yes,0 = no)?: ", 0

segment .text
read_sarray32:
    pusha
    mov ebx, [esp+36]   ;move starting position into ebx
    mov edx, [esp+40]   ;move max size into edx
    mov ecx, 0
read_loop:      
    ;mov    eax, prompt2
    ;call   print_string
    ;call   read_int
    call    getfloat
    inc     ecx;        increment counter

    call    print_nl
    call    putfloat
    call    print_nl
    cmp eax, 0  
    jz  Done
    jmp continue_loop
continue_loop:
    mov     [ebx], eax  ;move value into memory slot ebx
    add ebx, 4      ;move to next location for db word

    cmp ecx, edx    ; did i reach maximum values of array size?
    jz  Done
    jmp read_loop
Done:
    call    putfloat
    sub ecx, 1      ;to offset the 0 that was entered to exit loop
    mov [esp+44], ecx   ;moves counter back to stack
    popa
    ret
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is (hint for getting good answers: *always make it clear what question you're asking*) but ...

1. You appear to be expecting your floating-point number to be in `eax`. Why would it be there? That's an integer register. Your `getfloat` routine puts the number it's read onto the floating-point stack.
2. It's hard to tell what might have been wrong with your code for terminating the loop when 0 is entered in response to `prompt2` since that code is no longer there :-).
3. Obviously this isn't your problem, but you have `jmp continue_loop` immediately followed by the `continue_loop` label. Is this left over from an earlier version of the code?
4. I think the stack offsets from which you're loading `ebx` and `edx` near the start of `read_sarray32` are wrong; have you forgotten that `call` pushes the return address onto the stack? Specifically, I think that you're getting `ebx` = random nonsense and `edx` = 0; since your code is doing the equivalent of a do...while loop it'll run for ever -- or at least for 2^32 iterations.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, I was able to figure out how to read into an array with floats and print them out as well.

Comment: now i'm working on how to compute the sum of the float values in the current array...